# Equations from linear regression

Tags: regression, self-study, mathematical-statistics, mixed-model

**Notation.** Let $y$, $a$, and $b$ be $n\times 1$, $p\times 1$, and $q\times1$ real vectors. Let also $X$ and $Z$ be $n\times p$ and $n \times q$ real matrices.

Suppose that there is no solution, $a$, to $y = X a$.

**Question**. What are the conditions on $Z$ such that $y = Xa + Zb$ has no solution for each choice of $b$?

**Context**. I came across this problem in the context of linear regression. The fact that $y=Xa$ has no solution can be interpreted as "no hyperplane can perfectly fit the data". I am analysing an extension of this problem which has lead me to the need for finding something similar for "$y = Xa + Zb$ has no solution", but in this case $b$ is not fixed and can actually take any value in ${\mathbb R}^q$.

Comment: Is $b$ under "**Notation**" supposed to be the same as $u$ under "**Question**" (etc)? Are you thinking of this as a mixed effects model?

Comment: @gung Thanks for pointing out this notation inconsistency. I think it is now fixed. Yes, it is a mixed effects model, as you cleverly guessed.

Comment: @gung Although this is not a "self-study" question (it is not homework), it may look as such since I tried to be concise, I will leave this tag since I just need some hints to get a solution.

Comment: Our policy regarding what to call `[self-study]` is that it does not have to be from an actual class. Instead it refers to the type of question that it is.

Answer (score 1):

By assumption, $y - Xa \neq \mathbf 0$. So trivially, if $b$ is the zero vector, then there will be no solution to $y = Xa + Zb$. Assuming $b\neq \mathbf 0$, then we have

$$y = Xa + Zb \Rightarrow (Z'Z)^{-1}Z'(y - Xa) =b$$

So if $Z$ has a ["left-inverse"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_element#Matrices), there will be a $Z$ corresponding to a $b$. In order for $Z$ to have a left inverse, it must have full *column* rank. If $Z$ is not of full column rank, one could use a [pseudo-inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse), a case which is not clear from the question whether it is considered a "solution" or not.

Comment: I believe the OP means an *exact* solution.  That would be equivalent to $y$ being in the space spanned by the columns of $X$ and $Z$.  Any correct answer would have to be some kind of restatement of this (obvious) fact.